# Javascript: Show/Hide div based on dropdown list selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

The following is the HTML code for the dropdown list I have. Upon the selection of the `American` option, the American() Javascript function under `<head>` has to show another div. However this does not happen.

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function American(){
        <!-- Getting the Canadian -> Hiding it -> Turning 'on' the American. -->
        var Canadian = document.getElementById('text-inputs-Canadian');
        Canadian.style.display = 'none';

        var American = document.getElementById('text-inputs-American');
        American.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

The Dropdown List:

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
        <span>Standard</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="American();">American</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Canadian</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The div that takes on `#text-inputs-American` is set to be hidden initially like so:

```
#text-inputs-American{
    top:10px;
    margin-right:-200px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    display:none; /*Hides the input parameters until toggled by JS script*/
}
```

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

EDIT: Requested code, the div that has to be 'shown'

```
                <div id="text-inputs-American">
                            <span id="text-labels">S<sub>s</sub>(g)</span>
                            <input type="number" step="any" />
                            <span id="text-labels">S<sub>1</sub>(g)</span>
                            <input type="number" step="any" />
                            <span id="text-labels">T<sub>0</sub>(g)</span>
                            <input type="number" step="any" />
                            <span id="text-labels">T<sub>L</sub>(g)</span>
                            <input type="number" step="any" />
                </div>
```

Comment: the HTML-style comment inside of your JS function smells fishy to me.  What errors, if any, does your browser console report?

Comment: true! try to put comments inside your JS function with standard use of comments in Javascript. //Coment or /* multiline comment */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what ids have the divs exactly? I think you confuse how to use the getElementById method:

Try this:

```
 var Canadian = document.getElementById('text-inputs-Canadian');
 Canadian.style.display = 'none';

 var American = document.getElementById('text-inputs-American');
 American.style.display = 'block';
```

dont put '#' char to get the "text-inputs object" on the getElementById method.

Comment: Hm, I tried that, didn't fix it. I'll post the div that is being 'shown' above shortly

Comment: show your code , I want to see the divs and wich ids they have.

Comment: your code seems to be good, I dont know why dont works right now if you corrected the getElementById params.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with JQuery , your life is much easier with scripting

it can be done by just writing one single line of code:

$('#IdofTheDiv').show();//for showing the div http://api.jquery.com/show/
$('#IdofTheDiv').hide();//for hiding the div http://api.jquery.com/hide/

moreover you can even add the animations for the div hide/show using JQuery.

Comment: Wow this works... I'd use it, but I'd still like an answer to my original question.